# Python Saving to Mapped Shared Drive Error

Tags: python, save, shared, drive

I'm attempting to save a file to a mapped network drive Z: & The error I'm getting is SyntaxError: 'EOL while scanning string lateral'. I've tried this code with a local drive with no issue. Any tips on referencing a mapped shared drive.

```
with open ('test.txt','r') as file:
    text = file.read()
    with open(' Z:\\example.job.com@SSL\site\more\specific\folder\files','w') as file:
        file.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you not escape the backslashes?
try:

```
directory = r"Z:\\example.job.com@SSL\site\more\specific\folder\files"
with open ('test.txt','r') as file:
    text = file.read()
    with open(directory,'w') as file:
        file.write(text)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly but now I'm getting 'Permission Denied: Z:\\example.job.com@SSL\site\more\specific\folder\files'

Comment: Probably the write request is being denied. Look into whether the script has read/write access to the directory in question. Might be different than access permissions of your user, methinks. Might be based on where the python.exe is? (In admin install versus user install)